# Is Phasma the only Chrometrooper?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

We have seen the standard Stormtrooper colours in abundance - White, Black, and Red.

However, Phasma is the only chrome one I remember seeing.

How did she get to choose/design her own armour, and why can't anyone else?

[image]

Comment: Most likely yes, she seems to have gotten it from Palpatine's Naboo starfighter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Most likely yes.

As per the Force Awakens Visual dictionary (indirectly sourced through the wikia, states that she'd sourced her chrome armour from [Palpatine's Nabooian Yacht](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine%27s_yacht)

> Phasma wore armor coated in chromium salvaged from a Naboo yacht once owned by the Galactic Empire's Emperor Palpatine. Its polished finish helped reflect harmful radiation and was capable of deflecting weak blaster bolts, although the chromium served primarily as a symbol of past power. Phasma also believed that stormtrooper armor provided anonymity to an individual's gender, paying little heed to the antiquated belief that female stormtroopers were something new.
> <sub>[Star Wars Wiki - Phasma, Equiptment](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phasma#Equipment)</sub>

This is supported in her page on the Databank

> Clad in distinctive armor of salvaged chromium, Captain Phasma commands the First Order’s legions of stormtroopers
> <sub>[Star Wars Data Bank - Captain Phasma](http://www.starwars.com/databank/captain-phasma)</sub>

While more Chromium armour possibly could be made, it seems to signify her rank amongst the commanding triumvirate alongside Kylo Ren and Hux.

> Phasma served as one of the First Order’s commanding triumvirate, though she sometimes clashed with both the technocratic General Hux and the mysterious Kylo Ren.
> <sub>[ibid.](http://www.starwars.com/databank/captain-phasma)</sub>

Comment: I mean, it's a good answer but it sure makes her seem like a hypocrite in her treatment of Finn, "Hey, who told you you could remove that helmet" (goes off and builds herself a full set of customised shiny armour), shows what she really thinks about the uniform regulations :)

Comment: Well for her she probably wanted to stand out, especially considering she rose through the ranks so aggressively, but with Finn the idea is probably about allowing the soldiers a sense of being a real person, if they think they’re just soldiers they’ll be far mor loyal.